# Syncfusion charts not displaying after pushed to production

Tags: angular8, production-environment, .net-core-3.0, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

The code has been moved to production and the issue appears. Not able to load the pages with charts in it. Getting a fatal error on trying the same. The error received is, *Class constructor Orl cannot be invoked without 'new'*. This works fine in dev environment. I'm attaching images of the syncfusion packages installed and also the error obtained on trying to access pages with charts.

[image: syncfusion packages installed]

[image: Error obtained on trying to access pages with charts]

The compiler options are as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by changing the target type to es5.

Successfully reproduced the issue by using the 'ng serve --prod' command.